# obtengo fecha extraña de java SimpleDateFormat con un timestamp negativo de firebase para ordenar descendentemente

Tags: java, android, firebase, realtime-database

Solo quiero ordenar mis registros en orden descendente. Estoy usando el método ʻorderByChild () `de` DatabaseReference`:

```
private void listPersons() {

        databaseReference.child("Persons").orderByChild("timeStamp").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                listPersonas.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot objSnaptshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    Persona p = objSnaptshot.getValue(Person.class);
                    listPersons.add(p);
                }
    ....
        });
    }
```

Aquí están mis personas sin una marca de tiempo negativa:

```
2019/05/31 03:13:22 timestamp: ->1559333602000
2020/09/10 02:50:52 timestamp: ->1599767452000
2020/10/31 02:15:34 timestamp: ->1604171734423
```

No hay problemas antes de agregar el símbolo negativo, pero cuando pongo el símbolo negativo para usar ʻorderByChild ()` el siguiente método que uso para convertir el timestamp long me devuelve una fecha con años del siglo 19/20.

```
public String timeStampToDate(Object timestamp){

    String date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss").format(timestamp);

    return date;
}
```

Obtuve

```
2019/05/31 03:13:22 timestamp: -> -1559333602000
2020/09/10 02:50:52 timestamp: -> -1599767452000
2020/10/31 02:15:34 timestamp: -> -1604171734423

1919/03/02 11:44:25
1919/04/22 11:09:08
1920/08/02 10:46:38
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No sé por qué mis fechas son incorrectas, solo puse el símbolo negativo con el objetivo de poner mis registros en orden descendente. El método `public String timeStampToDate` está dentro de mi clase modelo `Person` Estoy usando este método dentro de mi `listview adapter`:

```
regdate.setText(personModel.timeStampToDate(personModel.getTimeStamp()));
```

De esta manera estoy registrando mis personas:

```
 Person p = new Person();
                p.setIdperson(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
                p.setName(name);
                p.setPhone(phone);
                p.setTimeStamp(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);

                databaseReference.child("Persons").child(p.getIdperson()).setValue(p);
```

Como podemos ver, estoy usando `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` para obtener una marca de tiempo de Firebase. Ahora debería registrar mi marca de tiempo multiplicando por -1. bien. Espero haber sido claro con mi problema.
gracias por adelantado.

**ACTUALIZACIÓN: 31/10/2020 18:22 MI SOLUCIÓN PARA MOSTRAR LA FECHA NORMAL:**

mi solución para mostrar una fecha normal y no incorrecta fue `multiplicar` la `marca de tiempo` por `-1` de esta manera obtengo la marca de tiempo normal y por lo tanto una fecha normal:

```
 public String timeStampToDate(Object timestamp){
            long value = Long.valueOf(String.valueOf(timestamp));
            long normaldate = value * -1;
            String date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss").format(normaldate);
            return date;
        }
```

Ahora estoy tratando de enviar a la base de datos firebase una "marca de tiempo negativa". Estaba leyendo que debería usar una "cloud functions? en serio tanto para eso?" que convierte la marca de tiempo automáticamente en negativa, pero no sé cómo hacerlo.
Gracias por adelantado.

Comment: Como se genera ese timestamp negativo? Porque si es por ejemplo un System.getCurrentTimeMillis(), un valor negativo no tiene sentido dado que el valor que devuelve la función representa la cantidad de milisegundos a partir de una fecha determinada (1ro de enero de 1970 UTC).

Comment: @Juan Según esta fuenta oficial de firebase https://youtu.be/nMR_JPfL4qg?t=280  `orderByChild()` requiere de un timestamp negativo para que ordene descendemente. E cambiado la forma de obtener el timestamp, ya no uso `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` por que no me permite generar un timestamp negativo. Lo que hago ahora es obtener el tiempo del sistema en milisegundos con Calendar `long tiempounix = calendar.getTimeInMillis();` y para pasarlo a negativo este long lo multiplico por `-1` ` p.setTimeStamp(tiempounix * -1);` mi método `timeStampToDate(long timestamp)` le e establecido zona horaria ("GMT-5")